# Cannot set property 'datarows' of undefined in ngHandsontable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, handsontable

I have a problem with the [ngHandsontable](https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable) component: i'm getting this error:

> Cannot set property 'datarows' of undefined

When trying to initialize the table. The code that i'm using is this:

```
<hot-table rowHeaders="true" startRows= "7" manualColumnResize="true" datarows="td"
                           settings="{  colWidths: [150, 150, 150, 150,150], colHeaders: colHeaders, contextMenu: ['row_above', 'row_below', 'remove_row'], afterChange: afterChange }">
  <hot-column data="COLUMN_1" title="'COLUMN_1'"></hot-column>
  <hot-column data="COLUMN_2" title="'COLUMN_2'"></hot-column>
  <hot-column data="COLUMN_3" title="'COLUMN_3'"></hot-column>
  <hot-column data="COLUMN_4" title="'COLUMN_4'"></hot-column>
  <hot-column data="COLUMN_5" title="'COLUMN_5'"></hot-column>
</hot-table>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.td = [{
    'COLUMN_1': ''
}];
```

Note that the `settings` object has some default properties that aren't present in my controller (`colHeaders` and `afterChange`). I've tried almost everything: i've removed the settings property, the datarows property, all the properties! without any change in the error message.

Looking into the source code of ngHandsontable i've found that this is the problematic line:

```
angular.forEach(bindingsKeys, function(key) {
  var mode = _this.scope[key].charAt(0);

  _this.$$isolateBindings[key] = {
    attrName: _this.scope[key].length > 1 ? _this.scope[key].substr(1, _this.scope[key].length) : key,
    collection: key === 'datarows',
    mode: mode,
    optional: false
  };
});
```

The error is with `_this.$$isolateBindings[key]` being `_this.$$isolateBindings` undefined.

I've no clue about this and i find that the configuration in my case is slightly different to the examples of the directive.

I'm actually using the 0.9.0 version, along with Handsontable 0.23.0 (free) and AngularJS 1.2.28.

What am i missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: Having the same issue with ngHandsontable 0.12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found this:

https://github.com/handsontable/ngHandsontable/blob/develop/index.html#L69

> Note: ngHandsontable supports angular in version 1.3 and greater.

**It's because of the older Angular version you are using. I just upgraded to Angular 1.5.8 and then it works.**

Comment: Awesome! I didn't found that comment. The 'solution' for this was to not use the library. Since isn't compatible i think that i have to wait until i can upgrade to a newer Angular version. Thank you!